# Environment variable not working in next js (12.2.2)

Tags: javascript, next.js

I followed the steps from official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables) but I'm facing problem, this is how I did :

next.config.js

```js
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  env : {
    MORALIS_ID: 'moralisId',
    MORALIS_SERVER: 'moralisServer'
  }
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

And I call it like that :

```js
<MoralisProvider serverUrl={process.env.MORALIS_SERVER} appId={process.env.MORALIS_ID}>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </MoralisProvider>
```

But when I console.log, I've got undefined and the error appear : `ReactMoralisError: Provide a "appId" provided to <MoralisProvider>`

So Next doesn't know the id.

What I did wrong ?

EDIT => even in my .env it doesn't work

EDIT AGAIN => I restart the server and it works, sorry guys and thanks for your time

Comment: Take a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser to expose env variables to the browser

Comment: I just tried : NEXT_PUBLIC_MORALIS_ID but still ubdefined in console.log and I get the error

Comment: But did you place your environment variables on a `.env.local` file instead of the `next.config.js` file?

Comment: Yes I also tried to place in the .env.local but same errors

Comment: You didn't export the config from the next.config.js file.

Comment: Yes I did, but didn't show sorry I edit

Answer (score 1):

Instead of next.config.js, Use .env.local, go throught https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

I restart the server and it works, sorry guys and thanks for your time

Comment: Yes, maybe you forgot to run the build. Next.js will replace process.env.customKey with its value at build time.